# Is there a reason to use express just for Ajax+DB actions?

Tags: node.js, express, module, server

I have a game server that gets only Ajax calls (not even static assets, it's a single page app and all assets served from CDN.) and serves back data from DB.
I thought using only Restify & MongoDB modules. Is there anything I will gain by using Express?

The app is a 2 player chess-like game. I need user authentication with tokens but I think I can easily write those on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use a large framework if you need just 1% of it.

Usually, if a job can be done by attaching several modules together (Restify & MongoDB in your case) then there is no point in using feature-full frameworks.

Finally, Express primary use case is websites.

---

P.S. The subject is sensitive to debates, so others might have different opinion.